# Not able to append values from a dataFrame to a google sheet at specific columns

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
import pandas as pd
import pygsheets
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

def csv_to_sheets():
   tokenPath ='path for service account file.json'
   scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

   credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(tokenPath, scopes=scopes)
   gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
   gs = gc.open('csv_to_gSheet')
   workSheet1 = gs.worksheet('sheet1')
   my_csv = pd.read_csv("my csv file path")
   my_csv_values = my_csv.values.tolist()
   gs.values_append('sheet1', {'valueInputOption': 'RAW'}, {'values': my_csv_values}, range='S:AE')`

csv_to_sheets()
```

After running the following code I get an error saying :

```
TypeError: values_append() got multiple values for argument 'range'
```

And if I remove the range from append method then the values get appended from the first column ie. from 'A till the data ends' but not in the columns I want ie. from 'S:AE'.
Also, how to append date in the first column and rest of the data in the specified range.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that the arguments of `values_append` is `values_append(range, params, body)`. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/spreadsheet.html?highlight=values_append#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.values_append) I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When this is refrected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
gs.values_append('sheet1', {'valueInputOption': 'RAW'}, {'values': my_csv_values}, range='S:AE')
```

#### To:

```
gs.values_append("sheet1!S:AE", {"valueInputOption": "RAW"}, {"values": my_csv_values})
```

- In this modification, the value of `my_csv_values` is appended to the last row of columns "S" to "AE".
- If you want to append the values to the last row of the data range, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      gs.values_append('sheet1', {'valueInputOption': 'RAW'}, {'values': my_csv_values}, range='S:AE')
    ```
  - To

    ```
      workSheet1.update("S" + str(len(workSheet1.get_all_values()) + 1), my_csv_values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
    ```

#### References:

- [values_append(range, params, body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/spreadsheet.html?highlight=values_append#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.values_append)
- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the solution. The first modification doesn't work, throws an error saying 'Invalid value at \'data.values\'. The second modification works perfectly. Can you also tell me how to put the date in first column as the rest now I'm able to append in specified range.

Comment: Yes @Tanaike will do that. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Kartikeya Kawadkar Thank you for your response.